# How to write a query to parse data into multiple columns from one column

Tags: sql, ms-access, parsing, join, union

I have an existing table (link #1) that I am trying to write a query for so that the query reformats the data as seen in the second link.  Basically it is a table listing the completed email types for a group of users.  The "Completed Type" is a single column with multiple values.   I am trying to parse out the individual values (3 of them) from the "Completed Type" into their own column with a total count.  I also would like to add a seperate column called "Completed" which is simply a sum of "Closed without response" and "Replied" for that particular user for that particular month.

I plan on then creating a pivot in Excel that will read off of the new query with the reformated data.   For the life of me, I can't figure out how to write this in SQL.  I tried creating individual queries to total the different "Completed" types and then tried to union them, but it is not working.

[Existing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdhtf.png)

[Future Query Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYSNZ.png)

Any advice or guidance you can provide in writing a SQL query in Access that will produce image # 2 would be GREATLY appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when and sum, for example:

```
select month,
   id,
   sum(case when completed_type = "completed" then 1 else 0 end) as completed
from table
group by month, id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a *crosstab* query:

```sql
TRANSFORM 
    Sum([Case Count]) AS [SumOfCase Count]
SELECT 
    [Month], 
    ID, 
    [Adjusted Name], 
    Mgr, 
    Sup, 
    Region, 
    Region2, 
    Sum(Abs([Completed Type] Not Like "Closed*")) AS Completed
FROM 
    Cases
GROUP BY 
    [Month], 
    ID, 
    [Adjusted Name], 
    Mgr, 
    Sup, 
    Region, 
    Region2
ORDER BY 
    ID, 
    [Month] DESC 
PIVOT 
    [Completed Type] In ("Replied","Sent","Closed without response");
```

Output:

[image]